# ffdshow equivalent for the Mac

Tags: video, osx-snow-leopard, media, video-codecs

When I was still on Windows XP, I used [ffdshow](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/ffdshow.htm) to take care of all my video and audio codecs needs (with fully customizable subtitles). I did not need any other video player except Windows Media Player.

Is there an ffdshow equivalent for the Mac? The objective is the same: that I shouldn't have to install any other video player, not even VLC, or the trial-bloatware-ridden DivX. I'm on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be '[perian](http://www.perian.org/)':

> Perian is a free, open source QuickTime component that adds native support for many popular video formats.

It uses code from ffmpeg, liba52, libmatroska. You can grab it from:

http://www.perian.org/

Comment: Does it work by now for `flv`? I remember having issues with those.

Comment: for me it worked with http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/flash/video/tutorial/example-flv.html

Comment: Can subtitles be customized? Like font, size, etc.